# Stopping Akka HTTP server

Tags: sockets, scala, akka

Having a simple Akka HTTP server:

```
package org.package.some

import akka.actor.{IOManager, IO, Actor}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

class HttpServerActor extends Actor {    
  val state = IO.IterateeRef.Map.async[IO.Handle]()(context.dispatcher)

  override def preStart() {
    IOManager(context.system) listen new InetSocketAddress(8000)
  }

  def receive = {
    case IO.NewClient(server) =>
      val socket = server.accept()
      state(socket) flatMap (_ => RequestProcessor.processRequest(socket))

    case IO.Read(socket, bytes) =>
      state(socket)(IO Chunk bytes)

    case IO.Closed(socket, cause) =>
      state(socket)(IO EOF None)
      state -= socket

    case "STOP" => 
      println("WHAT'S HERE??")
  }
}
```

How would one stop the server, i.e. close server socket on port 8000?

Just killing the actor does not have any effect: there remains a line in `netstat -a | grep 8000` saying that the port is still being listened to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IOManager.listen`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.2/akka/actor/IOManager.html#listen%28SocketAddress%29%28ActorRef%29%3aServerHandle) returns a [`ServerHandle`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.2/akka/actor/IO%24%24ServerHandle.html), which has a [`close`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.2/akka/actor/IO%24%24ServerHandle.html#close%28%29%3aUnit) method.

```
class HttpServerActor extends Actor {
  val state = IO.IterateeRef.Map.async[IO.Handle]()(context.dispatcher)
  var handle: ServerHandle = _

  override def preStart() {
    handle = IOManager(context.system) listen new InetSocketAddress(8000)
  }

  def receive = {
    // ...
    case "STOP" => 
      handle.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (`SocketHandle` should be replaced with `ServerHandle`)